# getNodeValue() truncates attribute content in org.w3c.dom.Node

Tags: java, android, xml, string, dom

I'm working on Android, and need to get a XML from an URL and retrieve some values. The download is ok, but some fields can contain HTML entities (like –). When I call the method getNodeValue() from the Node class (org.w3c.dom.Node), the value stops when it finds the & char, and truncates the String.

E.g.:

```
<title>Episode #56 &#8211; Heroes</title>
```

when I call the getNodeValue() only return "Episode #56 ".

Answer (score 0):

you may try some thing like this

```
String str = "<title>Episode #56 &#8211; Heroes</title>";
str = str.replaceAll("&", "amp;");
```

then try to parse 'str' it should work.

here is the sample implementation in pure with dom parser.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws XPathExpressionException {
    String str = "<title>Episode #56 &#8211; Heroes</title>";   
    str = str.replaceAll("&", "amp;");
    Document domDoc = null;
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes());
        domDoc = docBuilder.parse(bis);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    NodeList nlist = domDoc.getElementsByTagName("title");
    //System.out.println("child count  "+nlist.getLength());
    System.out.println("title value = "+nlist.item(0).getTextContent());
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but didn't work: String title = parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE); myObj.setTitle(title.replaceAll("&", "amp;")); // Same problem.

Comment: @Rafael it's working i have a given sample code, however it's not tested with dalvic runtime, but the logic can be implemented right?.